# Request for member tableView in something not a structure or union

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

Please help with this issue, I'm trying to populate my table cells with coreData db;

I'm porting an example from iPhone to iPad, 
the problem is that in the iPad in my table view. I'm using:

```m
@interface FailedBanksViewController : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

not the

```m
@interface FailedBanksListViewController : UITableViewController      <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

for the whole table view but a table inside my view,

so I get the error:

> "Request for member 'tableView' in something not a structure or union"

for my code,

look at the code below, which I hope is the only problem:

```m
#import "FailedBanksViewController.h"
#import "FailedBankInfo.h"


@implementation FailedBanksViewController
@synthesize context = _context;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"details.closeDate" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];

return _fetchedResultsController;    
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
}
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

//return [array count];
//return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}



- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = info.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", info.city, info.state];

}


//---insert individual row into the table view---

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//---try to get a reusable cell---

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



//---create new cell if no reusable cell is available---

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

      }
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;


//cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 


//return cell;

} 



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
return YES;
}




- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}


# FROM HERE THE ERRORS!!!
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        // Reloading the section inserts a new row and ensures that titles are updated appropriately.
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
// The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
[self.tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewController simply does not have a instance variable/property named tableView. Add the property yourself and implement alle necessary methods to replace a UITableViewController or keep using UITableViewController as base class.

Comment: hi, well thats my problem again, Im new to objC and dont know what you mean by this, how can I add the property myself? and how to implement the necessary methods? thanks